# Why are ball socket allen wrenches

Tags: maintenance, parts

Anecdotally, I see a lot of bike mechanics on the Internet use ball socketed allen wrenches. Is there an objective reason to using them over the 'regular' hex allen wrenches? Are there particular tasks or scenarios that make one style of wrench better than the other (e.g., prevent marring, or stripped socket hole)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate hex keys vs. combined multi-tool for bike adjustments?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16034/separate-hex-keys-vs-combined-multi-tool-for-bike-adjustments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming in at an angle like brake levers.
Or even *straight* in you can turn faster.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

The ball-end wrenches are really handy when there's an obstruction in front of the bolt, since they can be inserted at a slight angle.

But since the contact area is smaller, you're slightly more likely to strip the hole. So I would use a regular wrench when possible.

Comment: In the smaller sizes it's also possible to snap the ball clean off leaving it jammed in the bolt head. But they are useful.

Comment: I never use the ball-end for loosening a tight bolt, for the reasons stated above. But they are handy to unscrew the bolt 'til it comes out.